# Java HyperLinkListener JTextPane Null url

Tags: java, hyperlink, jtextpane

I have a JTextPane with a HyperLinkListener

```
  m_textPane.addHyperlinkListener(new HyperlinkListener()
  {

    @Override
    public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent hyperlinkevent)
    {
      EventType eventType = hyperlinkevent.getEventType();
      if (eventType == HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED)
      {

         URL url = hyperlinkevent.getURL();
         hyperLinkClicked(hyperlinkevent);

      }
    }
  });
```

The JTextPant is created with HTML and in this HTML file I have two Links.

```
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top" class="label">Telefon:</td>
                        <td class="value">

                            <a href="telnet:[PhoneNumber.primary.number]">
                              [PhoneNumber.primary.number] 
                            </a>     
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top" class="label">Mobil:</td>
                        <td class="value">[PhoneNumber:Mobil.number]</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top" class="label">Arbete:</td>
                        <td class="value">[PhoneNumber:Arbete.number]</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top" class="label">E-post:</td>
                        <td class="value">
                            <a href="mailto:[Email.primary.address|]">
                                [Email.primary.address|]
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

There is no problem getting the mailto protocol, returns "mailto" but the url for the telnet returns null

Any ideas? If any more information is needed tell me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `hyperlinkevent.getDescription();`  instead of `hyperlinkevent.getURL();`

```
public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent e) {
    if (e.getEventType() == HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED) {
        String description = e.getDescription();
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that but I still want the protocols to know wich functions to call. I guess i could just divide the string and get the information I want. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: You are welcome! Yeah that is the way to do. Good Luck!

Comment: I did it that way, it was the easiest way to do it. Thanks.